# How to detect on which value error occured?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, error-handling

Imagine that I have stored procedure which It trying to check If value is of type datetime and convert It to date.

I'm using `TRY CATCH` blocks to catch If error occured. I'm selecting `ERROR_LINE()` and `ERROR_MESSAGE()` in `CATCH` block.

Problem is that `ERROR_LINE()` returning only row number of procedure where error occured (and sometimes It returning wrong row) and `ERROR_MESSAGE()` returning only error's description like `Conversion failed when converting...`

In column are 100000+ values and I don't know on which value error occured. So I need to check over 100000 values?

Here is anyway to print Error message + Value on which error occured?

Comment: What you could do is start another `TRY CATCH` block in the first `CATCH` and use a `CURSOR` to loop through the values to see which one fails exactly. In the second `CATCH` you will then get the value on which the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `RAISERROR` as :

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (id INT, varchardate VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1,'200410212'),(2,'A'),(3,'2015-04-24 08:08:01.083')  


DECLARE @err_message nvarchar(255)


DECLARE @varchardate VARCHAR(200), @Id int
DECLARE @getvarchardate CURSOR
SET @getvarchardate = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT varchardate ,id
    FROM @Test
    OPEN @getvarchardate
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getvarchardate INTO @varchardate ,@Id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF isDate(@varchardate) = 0
        begin
        SET @err_message = @varchardate + ' and ' 
        + CAST (@Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Not valid Date'
        RAISERROR (@err_message, 11,1)
        END
        ELSE
        begin
        SELECT id,varchardate
        FROM @Test  
        END

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getvarchardate INTO @varchardate ,@Id
END
CLOSE @getvarchardate
DEALLOCATE @getvarchardate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
if(isDate(yourdatevalue))
begin
  --some code
end
else
begin
print yourdate + 'There is an error'
end
```